# Filtering results from is_in() OverPass query

Tags: overpass-api

I'm new with OverPass API.

I would like to get the country element where a certain point is contained.

As a first step I tried this:

```
is_in(48.856089,2.29789);
out;
```

It gives me all the areas which contain the given coordinate, including regions, provinces...

So now, I would like to filter the country only. In the results, I can see that the country element is determined by the `admin_level` attribute, which must be equal to `2`.

So, in order to filter my first request, I tried this:

```
is_in(48.856089,2.29789)[admin_level="2"];
out;
```

But with [OverPass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/f51), it gives me the following error:

> Error: line 1: parse error: ';' expected - '[' found.

I read that areas are an extended data type (compared to nodes, ways, and relations). Is it the reason why I can't filter my results?

How can I filter results from the `is_in` query, by `[admin_level="2"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine `is_in` with any additional filter criteria. The proper way to do this is as follows, where `._` refers to the area result returned by `is_in`.

```
is_in(48.856089,2.29789);area._[admin_level="2"];
out;
```